# Como calcular cuantos items estan asociados a un ID

Tags: excel, vba, condiciones, formulas

Estoy trabajando en excel y en una de las formulas que tengo que hacer, ocupo calcular cuantos items diferentes están asociados a un ID en especifico. Tengo las siguientes columnas

```
      ID               Item 
OPX-0020433077  Continuity Services
OPX-0020433077  Storage Services
OPX-0020433077  Midrange Services
OPX-0020433077  Storage Services
OPX-0020433079  Digitization
OPX-0020433080  CPS-Other 3rd Party Products and Services
OPX-0020433080  CPS-Other 3rd Party Products and Services
OPX-0020433080  CPS-Other 3rd Party Products and Services
OPX-0020433081  Foundational Support Services
OPX-0020433081  Storage Services
OPX-0020433081  Foundational Support Services
OPX-0020433081  Storage Services
OPX-0020433081  Midrange Services
```

Por lo tanto el resultado que debo obtener es algo como el siguiente.

```
     ID            Count
OPX-0020433077       3  
OPX-0020433079       1
OPX-0020433080       1
OPX-0020433081       3
```

Esto debido a que el id OPX-0020433077  tiene 4 items, pero hay uno de ellos que es repetido, por lo tanto se contaría como si fueran 3, ya que el repetido se ignora.

He estado usando el siguiente código.

```
=COUNT(IF($A$2:$A$11=A2,$B$2:$B$11))
```

Pero esta formula siempre me devuelve 0. Alguna idea de como podría hacerlo, puede ser usando VBA o funciones de excel directamente. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que lo mejor sería quitar duplicados y luego resumir con una tabla dinámica, pero por si acaso, sin usar VBA, se me ocurre lo siguiente:

Usar una columna auxiliar, en la que devuelva 1 si es la primera vez que aparece ese ID asociado a dicho ITEM, y que devuelva 0 si no es el caso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para esta cuenta, he usado la siguiente fórmula:

```
=SI(CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO($A$2:A2;A2;$B$2:B2;B2)=1;1;0)
```

La conjugamos con rangos dinámicos (solamente dejamos como referencia absoluta la primera coordenada) para que así la cuenta se actualice sola, según se vaya ampliando el rango. De esta manera, la primera vez que aparece, por ejemplo, `OPX-0020433077  Storage Services`la fórmula devuelve un 1, pero las veces sucesivas que aparezca, devolverá 0.

Luego, con una tabla dinámica resumimos, y sumamos dicha columna:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así obtenemos, por ejemplo, que el ID `OPX-0020433077` tiene 3 ítems en total.

Espero que puedas adaptar esto a tus necesidades.

Comment: Buen punto @Elier Sánchez E-Infantes con la función `CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO` sólo quería acotar que para la sugerencia de quitar duplicados, estos tendrían que ser para los valores concatenados en `ID` e `ITEM` por ejemplo `OPX-0020433077 Storage Services` serían dos (02), al irse uno de ellos quedaría tres (03) `OPX-0020433077`, pero lo que propones me parece más rápido, porque se trabaja con los datos crudos directamente sin filtrar.